# Rapidclipse & testing

Tags: testing, rapidclipse

I am currently evaluating Rapidclipse (v3.2.1 on Windows 10 64 bits).

I have noted that the project layout created by default by Rapidclipse does not include any test or test resource folders, nor does the default pom have any provisions for test structures.

Moreover, in the documentation on the Rapidclipse site there is no reference to any test approach for the Rapidclipse projects.

Maybe I'm missing somethimg, but I would like to know what would be the recommended test approach for a Rapidclipse project; I understand that the project in the end is a pure java project, but I would expect that Rapidclipse would provide an opinionated and managed approach to testing by creating the necessary fixture and infrastructure, as with the GUI or the persistence layer.

Is there something I'm missing or overlooking?

Thanks for any hint,

Gianni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project structure has been changed in Rapidclipse 10, so now you can easily create unit tests from the 'Project Management' view under **test-java** using the "New JUnit Test Case" wizard.

After doing that you can run the tests by right clicking the project and selecting "Run As -> JUnit Test"